# Sending S3 Signed URL Pdf as email Attachment

Tags: java, pdf, amazon-s3, email-attachments, amazon-ses

Am trying to send `S3` pdf documents as e-mail attachment. I use the signed URL of the document and build `MimeBodyPart` as below.

```
 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

 // have another MimeBodyPart for text/html content



BodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new URLDataSource(attachmentUrl)));
attachment.setFileName(<filename>);
attachment.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setContent(<filename>,"application/pdf");
multipart.addBodyPart(attachment)
```

The problem am facing is the attachment is successfully attached but without any content. I meant it's always 1KB. And unable to open/view anything.

The above problem is faced for `pdf` files alone. But if I give some image URL and remove the `setContent`, `setDisposition`  everything is working as expected.

Debugged some more looking at raw email could see the headers for the attachment are different.

When attached the image from this [URL](https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png)

```
Content-Type: image/png; name=googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

But when I attach any PDf/S3 signed one via a URL I get as below

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=structures-and-c.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=structures-and-c.pdf
```

The exception when I get when I don't explicitly set the content type. The same is not being complained for an image.

```
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: In Content-Type string <pdf>, expected '/', got null

    at javax.mail.internet.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:80)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1486)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1148)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:498)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1509)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2238)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2198)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1877)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1854)
```

Comment: Remove these 2 lines: `attachment.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);` and `attachment.setContent(<filename>,"application/pdf");`. Replace them with this one line: `attachment.setFileName(<filename>);`.

Comment: That did not help. If we remove those for PDF content-type is going as null and it fails.I tried by including the `setFileName` along with the above setter result remains same.

Comment: OK - understood. When I used the code in the question, I ggot the same issue as you. When I make my changes the issue is resolved for me. (I am assuming the signed URL is valid, by the way.)

Comment: I tried with a signed URL as well as any pdf in a public URL. Facing a similar issue. How does your signed URL look like? Can you share?

Comment: Sounds like the signed URL issue is not relevant if your code fails with unsigned URLs to PDFs, elsewhere. (I don't have an unexpired signed URL to share).

Comment: Figured out. It was more of the signed URL issue where the content type was not set properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using S3 signed url for PDF using the above way no need to set the below.

```
attachment.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setContent(<filename>,"application/pdf");
```

Ensure when you are generating signed URL it sets the below properly

```
GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectName)
                    .responseContentDisposition("attachment;filename=" + objectName)
                    .responseContentEncoding("base64")
                    .responseContentType("application/pdf")
```